# Does sending mail via nodemailer in firebase cloud functions require billing account?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I had deployed a firebase cloud function to send a welcome mail when a user signs in for the first time.
In the firebase console, in firebase cloud function log messages, I saw this error message when the function was invoked.

***Error Message:***

> Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions

Is it not possible to send emails for free using firebase cloud functions? if it is possible, please explain the procedure. (Possiblly with a sample code)

**Edit 1:**
1. I am currently using nodemailer for sending mail.
2. I am using Gmail as the mail service.

Comment: The nodemailer package itself is irrelevant. But if you configure it to call a non-Google mail service, you will need to be on a paid plan. Note message is a **warning** that is printed in any case; seeing it is not necessarily a problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How to call a Google mail service? Any reference would be great.

Comment: If you're using a non-Google service from Cloud Functions, you project will need to be on a paid plan. Calls to 3rd party services are rejected on the free plan, to prevent abuse of Cloud Functions as a DoS vector to those services. If you're trying to use gmail and having problems with code that you're deploying, please edit your question to include the [minimal complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: are you able to figure it out? I am using nodemailer as well and configured   var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'xyz@gmail.com',
      pass: 'xxxxxxxxx'
    }
  }); but still getting the billing error

Answer (score 0):

```
Does sending mail via nodemailer in firebase cloud functions require billing account?
```

NO, You **DO NOT need a billing account** to send email via nodmailer using cloud functions.

I was getting the billing error as yours in my cloud function. And I have done 2 simple steps and it's gone.

**1.** In your gmail account setting, enable [Less secure app access](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) to **ON**

**2.** Also go to this link and click continue https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha .

After doing the above 2 steps, the billing error is gone, and email is sending successfully from the cloud function.

And here is my nodejs code for your refernce:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'xyzz@gmail.com',
    pass: '123'
  },
});
exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: '"Test." <noreply@firebase.com>',
    to: 'xyz@gmail.com'
  };
  // Building Email message.
  mailOptions.subject = 'Thanks and Welcome!'
  mailOptions.text = 'Thanks you for subscribing to our newsletter. You will receive our next weekly newsletter.'

  try {
    await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log('subscription confirmation email sent to');
    return res.send('Sended');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error);
    return res.send(error.toString());
  }
});
```

You can test locally before you deploy it

```js
firebase serve --only functions
```

you will get a link http://localhost:5000/project-name/us-central1/sendMail; paste it in the browser and the cloud function will run. If any errors it will show up in the browser and console/powershell